# Converting Videos using ffmpeg (mkv to mp4)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I've been trying to convert a series of mkv videos to mp4 using ffmpeg. I've tried the following and it doesn't seem to actually keep the 60fps frame rate, and it also removes the second audio track.

```
ffmpeg -ac 2 -r 60 -i video.mkv video.mp4
```

I know there are a couple threads out there about converting while *re-encoding* but I don't really know how to go about that. I want to make sure that the dual audio tracks are preserved as well.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: log? the command works fine but it doesn't output the kind of file that i want. I just included what I had used and why it wasn't what I wanted.